# Abandoning causality. Tell me it ain't so

Tags: quantum-gravity, causality, superposition

What is the gross oversimplification in this thought example?

from [Quantum Mischief Rewrites the Laws of Cause and Effect](https://www.quantamagazine.org/quantum-mischief-rewrites-the-laws-of-cause-and-effect-20210311/) (Quantamagazine)

> Alice and Bob, the stars of so many thought experiments, are cooking
> dinner when mishaps ensue. Alice accidentally drops a plate; the sound
> startles Bob, who burns himself on the stove and cries out. In another
> version of events, Bob burns himself and cries out, causing Alice to
> drop a plate.
>
> Over the last decade, quantum physicists have been exploring the
> implications of a strange realization: In principle, both versions of
> the story can happen at once. That is, events can occur in an
> indefinite causal order, where both “A causes B” and “B causes A” are
> simultaneously true.
>
> “It sounds outrageous,” ...

Comment: What about the explanation in the directly following paragraph (and also the rest of the article) about a photon state being put into a superposition of "first B, then A" and "first A, then B" is unclear to you?

Comment: It is more a bad analogy than a gross oversimplification. The text you quote uses a real-life situation to illustrate a quantum phenomenom. This never works and actually makes QM more difficult to grasp by only overemphasizing its "outrageous" features (which are indeed a fact of the matter, but a quite subtle one). In short: QM is not about people or cats.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin So I take it this is not about using quantum messaging in a relativistic universe (with Alice & Bob), but instead is about applying relativity to quantum phenomena.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen The title of the [original research paper](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/3/3/e1602589) is "Experimental verification of an indefinite causal order," which is thoroughly misleading. The experiment produces a quantum superposition of $A$-then-$B$ with $B$-then-$A$, but the events $A$ and $B$ are not in any cause-and-effect relationship with each other. It's not even a matter of applying relativity. There is no new physics here, just a new way to [yank people's chains](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull%2Fyank%20someone%27s%20chain).